# Problem with styling javafx mixed barchart/linechart

Tags: java, javafx

I encountered a frustrating problem with styling a javafx graph. Hope that somebody can help me out.

Using the JavaFx-library I made a StackedBarChart and a LineChart combined in one scene:

```
StackPane stackpane = new StackPane();
stackpane.getChildren().addAll(lineChart,stackedBarChart);
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

Style.css looks as follows:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke-width: 4px;-fx-stroke: #3F48CC; -fx-stroke-dash-array: 12 12 12 12;} 
.default-color0.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #AA3B3B } 
.default-color1.chart-bar { -fx-bar-fill: #FFC000 } 
.chart-plot-background { -fx-background-color: transparent; }
```

The resulting image is:
[Resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oduoc.png)

Now I want to turn everything that is lightgrey (the background) into white. I tried that by adding the following styling:

```
.chart {-fx-background-color: white}
```

But this simple action makes the linechart (with the title of the chart) disappear:

[Resulting image after adding style line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khwis.png)

It seems that the .chart class refers to the background of the barchart, which is covering the linechart. Therefore: how to set the background of the entire image? Or should I make the background of the barchart-layer transparent and the background of the linechart-layer white? And if so: how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Guessing: `.bar-chart {-fx-background-color: transparent;}` *after* the `.chart {-fx-background-color: white;}`?

Comment: No, the order of lines in the stylesheet doesn't matter. I resolved the issue by adding this line to the stylesheet:

.root {
  -fx-background-color: white; 
}
Thanks!

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Charts have transparent background by default, I guess. If you want to be specific, just style the background of the stack pane.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SceneBuilder, you can drop a control onto the design page, then click on View / Show CSS Analyser and it will open a window at the bottom that shows all of the styling properties for the selected object. If an object has multiple components on it, you can click on each one and see the related styling options.

Also, at the top of that lower window, you will see and arrow in a circle ... click on it to see more sub layer styling info that is related to whatever you have selected in the design window.

[image]